# Graphical modeler calculator missing in QGIS3

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

There used to be a calculator in the modeler-only tools in QGIS graphical modeler. But I notice that it is missing in QGIS3. How do I do numerical calculations as part of the model? For example, take input in km and convert it to meters for certain algorithm.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use expression within a model. For instance, my distance is in kilometers. But I want to do my buffer with meters.

Next to the distance field in the buffer algorithm, you can choose an expression input. And then use the number input with a formula.

[image: model with expression]

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for. Being able to use the expression within the model removes the need for a separate calculator algorithm and is much more powerful.